# How to concatenate two strings in iOS when calling Data From webservice, \n (new line) also not working?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am retrieving data from webservice like this

```
NSString *str_Txt = [rootElement stringValueForNode:@"info"];
NSLog(@"str_Txt is %@",str_Txt);   // Data Receive


output:

str_Txt is \n\n\nInfo \n\n\nSebastian Vettel \n\n Alonso
```

I want when \n comes line will break

like this

```
textview.text  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", str_Txt];
NSLog(@"textview is %@",textview.text);

output:    // supposing output

textview is


Info


Sebastian Vettel


Alonso
```

but the problem is that the when i run that code output again come like this:

textview is \n\n\nInfo \n\n\nSebastian Vettel \n\n Alonso

Line is not breaking. \n is not working.

I want to do something like this:

```
// textview.text =@"\n\n\nInfo \n\n\nSebastian Vettel \n\n Alonso";
textview.text  = @""%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", str_Txt]";
NSLog(@"textview is %@",textview.text);
```

so that my output will shoe like this:

output:    // supposing output

```
textview is


Info


Sebastian Vettel


Alonso
```

Any idea, how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure your string doesn't contain literal "\n" strings rather than newlines?

Comment: Yes, There is no ""   I used sebastian Vettel \n\n Alonso , not like this sebastian Vettel "\n\n" Alonso.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand - if there are literal `\ ` and `n` characters in your string rather than newline characters, you'll see the behaviour you're getting.

Comment: I tried `NSString * text = @"\n\n\nInfo \n\n\nSebastian Vettel \n\n Alonso";` `self.textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", text];` and it correctly shows the newlines

Comment: Sir i am getting XML like this <info><![CDATA[\n\n\n\n\nInfo \n\n\nSebastian Vettel \n\n Alonso]]></info> and retrieving like this NSString *str_Txt = [rootElement stringValueForNode:@"info"];
NSLog(@"str_Txt is %@",str_Txt);   // Data Receive

Comment: @Gabriele Petronella , yeah i am also getting same output when i do this. But I am not doing like this I am doing another way what i have written above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the text which you're getting is showing you "`\n`" and hence as Carl Norum mentioned, these are not new line character but normal literal string. You can try to replace the occurrence of "`\\n`" with "`\n`".

```
NSString *new = [old stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"\\n" withString:@"\n"];
```

This should help you achieve what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks aloot... Now the code is working properly... You are genius... Thnx again....

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
textview.text  = [str_Txt componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```